# Failed assertion: line 234 pos 15: 'image != null': is not true

Tags: flutter

I am getting this issue. The red ones in the rectangle are not working and giving errors.
but product 3 is working fine and fetching all data and displaying properly.

[image]

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Send the code for proper helping and till that
Check the image link you got from the API.